# Reading HGT Files (SRTM)

Tags: pseudocode, .hgtags

Presently I am having problems obtaining elevation point data from the SRTM3 format (.hgt) from NASA. I wish to use the data for creating a program that creates a 2d panoramic illustration of the given area based on the elevation points extracted.

I've exhausted a lot of resources from the Net but still to no avail. 
What I want to ask is a form of pseudocode for me to be able to read .hgt files and obtain data from them so I can feed something to my program.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You Could use [UniboGeoTools](https://code.google.com/p/unibo-geotools/) a very small java library that provides Elevation Info in two way:  SRTM and Google Elevation Api. 
Take a look at the test to understand how it works ..

Answer (score -1):

a pseudocode is:

```
file a = '~/S41W072.hgt'

size = 1201*1201
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
   int bb= a.readByte();
   printScreen(bb,i%1201,(1201-(int)(-1+i/1201)));
}
```

I have java code somewhere, if I find it I'll upload